# Creating network share on DMZ with Powershell, firewall rules?

Tags: powershell, firewall

I'm trying to create a network shared folder on a server that sits on the DMZ (which is fairly locked down) using powershell and have requested a rule to be put in the firewall to allow TCP port 445 for this to happen, but is this the correct protocol and port that powershell uses to do this?

I have the following script which i have used to create folders on domain servers and it works fine

```
  If (!(Test-Path -Path $dirpath))
  {
     Write-Host "Creating share: $dirpath"
     New-Item $dirpath -Type directory
     ForEach ($user In $accesslist)
     {
        Set-FullControl -Principal $user -Folder $dirpath
     }
  }
  Else
  {
     Write-Host "Folder $dirpath already exists" -Foreground Green
  }
```

Where $dirpath can be \SERVENAME\d$\folder

But I'm not sure what firewall rule I need to set-up in order to do this on the DMZ server, what does the firewall need to allow through?

After the share has been set-up I copy installation files over and execute the install (a windows service) again all of this is done using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

445 is only one of the ports required for smb, you also need 137-139. Aside from that you will obviously also need proper permissions.